# Blank editor window with Scala-IDE

Tags: scala, scala-ide

When opening a Scala file in the Scala-IDE eclipse plugin, the "open file" is just blank and a popup with `java.lang.nullPointerException` is given. Is there any workaround or fix that can be done?

Eclipse version: 4.3.0
Scala-IDE version: 3.0.0.v_2-10 and/also current nightly

[image: An open .scala file]

Comment: Workaround would be to use the release not the nightly.

Comment: If you mean Scala-IDE, that was what I tried. However I found out that Scala-IDE has problems with Eclipse 4.3, so I replaced that version with Eclipse 4.2 and now it works.

Comment: Do you have the stack trace for that nullPointerException ?